# Active Admin Customization using Raty Js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using active admin to control admin's page.
I have a situation where admin can edit an users rating. Right now it is given as a drop down list as follows

```
 f.input :total_rating, as: :select, collection: 0..5, :input_html => { :class => "check_class" }
```

I want to make this a star rating.. for other places in project i used raty js to give star rating. So im trying to bring this raty js into the active admin